# Selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element, seems indepedent from time waiting

Tags: python, exception, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to access a button on website using Selenium.
I'm using the find_element() method but I always have the same issue.

[This is the HTML code of the web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7EHJ.png)

The code causing an issue is:

`myButton=driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="container_page"]/div[1]/a')`

And this is what I get on Terminal:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="container_page"]/div[1]/a"}
```

I've tried it on Wikipedia, and it works well.
I have tried it with the full XPATH and it doesn't change things.

I have seen a lot people saying it is because the web page is not totally loaded and the command is too quick, but I've tried adding time and even WebDriverWait(driver, 20) method but it does not work either:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/a"))).click()
```

Does anybody have an idea about the cause of the problem ?

Thank you

Comment: Edit your question and share your code trial, error trace, HTML of the application in the form of text. If it's public, share the URL of the application.

Comment: Please don't provide source code as images, instead copy the code in the question if necessary

Answer (score 0):

A `NoSuchElementException` happens when the driver is unable to find an element when using your search strategy. Or, in other words, your `xpath` doesn't point to an element in the current context. This typically happens when the element is on the website, but is found in a different context (e.g. an `iFrame`, `Frame`, or `#shadow-root`).

If your element is not found in another context, then your locator strategy needs to be updated, or you need to wait for the element to appear on the page.